# chrt has no effect on changing scheduling policy

Tags: ubuntu, process, scheduling

I would like to change the scheduling policy of a process via `chrt`, however, as you can see below, it has no effect on the systemd process. This is an example and I tried other processes, too. It remains SCHED_OTHER.

```
    PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU  %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND
   1862 mahmood   20   0   24980  11908   9768 S   5,9   0,1   0:00.09 systemd


$ sudo chrt -p 1862
pid 1862's current scheduling policy: SCHED_OTHER
pid 1862's current scheduling priority: 0
$ sudo chrt -f -p 1862
pid 1862's current scheduling policy: SCHED_OTHER
pid 1862's current scheduling priority: 0
$ sudo chrt -p 1862
pid 1862's current scheduling policy: SCHED_OTHER
pid 1862's current scheduling priority: 0
```

Any idea about that?

Comment: Even if it changes the scheduling class, the change does not have any effect.
I started some parallel build with scheduling class idle and it still preempts processes running with normal scheduling class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ sudo chrt -f -p 1862
```

You are not using chrt according to what `man chrt` tells :

> chrt -r -p priority PID

When changing the scheduling policy, the priority parameter is **not** optional. Use `chrt --max` to check the ranges of acceptable values.

```
$ chrt -p 21549
pid 21549's current scheduling policy: SCHED_OTHER
pid 21549's current scheduling priority: 0
$ chrt -f -p 10 21549
$ chrt -p 21549
pid 21549's current scheduling policy: SCHED_FIFO
pid 21549's current scheduling priority: 10
```

Use `chrt -o -p 0 21549` to restore original SCHED_OTHER policy + priority.

Comment: You are right. Thank you. However, when I set `sudo chrt -f -p 10 1862`, the top command shows that the PR column for that process is -11 and not 10.

Comment: @mahmood Don't ask me why but top has always been messy when reporting about priorities. Check using "ps -eHo pid,ppid,tid,class,rtprio,ni,pri,comm" instead

Answer (score 0):

Bad news: This migth be a `chrt` bug.

```
sudo strace -e /sched -o /tmp/strace chrt -f -p 94495
```

only shows a syscall to `sched_getattr`, but not to `sched_setattr`, as would be necessary:

```
cat /tmp/strace
sched_getattr(94495, {size=56, sched_policy=SCHED_OTHER, sched_flags=0, sched_nice=0, sched_priority=0, sched_runtime=0, sched_deadline=0, sched_period=0, sched_util_min=0, sched_util_max=0}, 56, 0) = 0
+++ exited with 0 +++
```

So, the setting is not even attempted.

Comment: PEBCAK more likely than a chrt bug. See my answer.